# UISplitViewController in portrait on iPhone always show master and detail in iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

`UISplitViewController` in **portrait** on iPhone always show master and detail in **iOS 8**

I try to subclass `UISplitViewController` and config it to show master and detail at the same time. but no any effect.

```
class APPSplitViewController: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
        maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 32.0
        minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 32.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

How to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UISplitViewController use show side-by-side only in horizontally regular environment (new TraitCollection size)

> The split view controller determines the arrangement of its child view controllers based on the available space. In a horizontally regular environment, the split view controller presents its view controllers side-by-side whenever possible. In a horizontally compact environment, the split view controller acts more like a navigation controller, displaying the primary view controller initially and pushing or popping the secondary view controller as needed. You can also ask the split view controller to prefer a specific arrangement by assigning a value to the [preferredDisplayMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/preferredDisplayMode) property.

Solution. 
You have to change TraitCollection of SplitViewController. How do this:

- Create a ViewController and add your SplitViewController as a child.
- Override traitCollection with size .Regular for your child (UISplitViewController)

**ViewController Wrapper**

```
class TraitOverrideViewController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureSplitVC()
  }


  private func configureSplitVC() {

    let splitVC = self.childViewControllers[0] as UISplitViewController
    setOverrideTraitCollection(UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .Regular), forChildViewController: splitVC)
  }
}
```

In iOS 8 UISplitViewController uses [Adaptive User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/) and TraitCollections to show its content.
It shows different style depending on the size of and type of the view. You can change by technic I explain above.
You can get more info in WWDC video about [Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=216)

Comment: Hi Konstantin Koval, Thanks for your helping. It's a great answer. I still have a question. Why I lost the detail view?

Comment: Try to set primaryColumnWidth

Comment: or you have to call showDetailViewController, to shod detailsViewController for default item, as example at index 0