# Xcode - How to make that master and detail controller shows at the same time?

Tags: xcode, swift, ipad, interface, uisplitviewcontroller

I read about it and I found [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670930/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-always-show-master-and-detail-in-ios) but when I did it I got an error "fatal error: Array index out of range". I have `UISplitViewController`, `UITabBarController` (it is master) and several `UIViewControllers`. I want to show both the master controller and the detail controller at the same time in portrait orientation like it is looks in horizontal orientation. Please help me.

My interface is looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution. I made a class for the `UISplitViewController` then I wrote the following code within it.

```
import UIKit

class Split: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func splitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController, shouldHideViewController vc: UIViewController, inOrientation orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```